# No redirect back to question after posting a comment

Tags: bug, ios-app

Basically the title says everything. There is no action after I post a comment, just a notification that the comment was posted successfully and white screen.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 12.0 (Build 16A366)

Comment: Jeas, it is, the exact same problem. Sorry for this dupe.